# HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url); giving exceptions

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

I am trying to do a very simple thing which was working a couple of days ago.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
```

It is giving the following error

```
Caused by:
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported cookie spec: default
                at org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpecRegistry.getCookieSpec(CookieSpecRegistry.java:110)
                at org.apache.http.cookie.CookieSpecRegistry$1.create(CookieSpecRegistry.java:163)
                at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:157)
                at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)
                at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:166)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:485)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:878)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:84)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:109)
                at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
```

I faced this error earlier using a deprecated client and I changed it to using HTTPClientBuilder. I am not sure why it is giving on HTTPGet.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what version of HttpClient are you using?

Comment: Sorry, My bad. I should have mentioned that in my question. I am using 4.3.

Comment: this does not make sense. 'default' cookie policy was introduced in version 4.4

Comment: I would love to have a followup on this. We're hitting the exact same problem: our code suddenly stopped working, and we get the exact same exception and callstack. I don't know what changed since it last worked. Maybe another package has been updated? Did you end up finding what the cause of the problem was?

Answer (score 9):

It's a bug from apache httpclient, version `4.4 beta 1` has this bug, but version `4.3.6` works fine for me.

If you are using maven, use following in pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

And **don't** update it to 4.4 before they fix this bug.

Comment: have you got a reference to the bug? can we upvote it?

Comment: @Friso I didn't research the bug any more after I fix the issue by changing the version. I feel issues like this don't worth much time.

Comment: Also breaks Sardine 5.0

Answer (score -1):

try this code

http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1'));
}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30118502)